# Apache and Let's Encrypt - Chain issues: Incorrect order, Extra certs

Tags: apache-http-server, letsencrypt

I have my webserver configured with Let's Encrypt (CentOS 6.10, Apache 2.2). When running a security analysis on my site with [Qualsys's SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html), I get the following warning:

> Chain issues: Incorrect order, Extra certs

My Apache configuration file looks like this:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain/fullchain.pem
```

How can I get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you are using `fullchain.pem`. Since you are using Apache 2.2, and in order to avoid duplicating the certificate, you simply need to use `chain.pem` instead, like so:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain/chain.pem
```

With Apache 2.4 you could also remove the `SSLCertificateChainFile` directive and change the `SSLCertificateFile` to link `fullchain.pem`, like so:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain/privkey.pem
```

Reference: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/incorrect-order-and-extra-certificate-error/8759